# Realm: How to tell if a field is nullable via DynamicRealm?

Tags: kotlin, realm, nullable, realm-java

Does `DynamicRealm` offer a way to determine if a field is nullable on a kotlin `RealmModel` subclass?

For example, given the following realm models:

```
open class IntObj(
    var i: Int = 1
): RealmObject()
```

```
open class NullIntObj(
    var i: Int? = null
): RealmObject()
```

If I fetch a dynamic realm object representation of each type and try to determine the field type of parameter "i" via `dynamicRealmObj.getFieldType("i")`, they both return "INTEGER".

Is there a way I can determine the nullability of a field on a dynamic realm object? Do I have to use reflection to try and determine what the underlying Java field is annotated with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I'm an idiot - turns out `dynamicRealm.isNullable(fieldName)` totally exists :)

Comment: I believe you can most likely accept your own answer now.